# Height in HTML Content in Textview - Android

Tags: android, html, textview, android-fragments

Good day!

I have an application that uses html.fromhtml() to style my paragraph content.

But i don't have any control of the `<br>` or the `<p>` tag in terms of the spacing (vertical) they created since css is not working in android.

Is there anyway how to do it?

Here is my code so far:

```
 con.setText(Html.fromHtml("<b>Lorem Ipsum Dolor</b><br/><br/>" +
            "<p>Lorem Ipsum Dolor</p>"+
            "<p>Crest PTY 1000</p>" +
            "<p>Phone: (02) 8217-1300</p>"+
            "<p>BSB 032-0052</p><br/>" +            
            "<b>Trading Hours</b><br/><br/>"+
            "<p>Monday – Thursday 9:30am – 4:00pm</p>" +            
            "<p>Friday 9:30am – 5:00pm<br/></p>" +
            "<p>Saturday 10:00am – 1:00pm</p><br/>"+            
            "<b>Languages</b><br/><br/>"+
            "Mandarin, Cantonese, Bahasa Indonesia,<br/><br/> Japanese, Vietnamese, Greek<br/><br/><br/>"+          
            "<b>Morning Style</b><br/><br/>"+           
            "Safe deposit box - This one<br/>"+
            "Internet Banking kiosks<br/>"+
            "Night safe<br/>" +
            "Coin Deposit Machine<br/>" +
            "Cash Exchange Machine<br/>" +
            "Migrant Services<br/><br/>"));
```

Screenshot

[image]

Any help is very much appreciated

Answer (score 2):

You can set the line spacing of a TextView by using:
`con.setLineSpacing(5, 1);`

[TextView.setLineSpacing(float, float)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#setLineSpacing(float,%20float))

Comment: Ah, you are using paragraph tags "<p></p>". So the spacing is normal behaviour. If you delete those tags and just add a "<br />" to the end of the line, will that work?

Comment: if only one `<br/>` tag added it will not generate a vertical spacing between the title and content. but if i will also add two `<br/>` tags, it will generate the same problem of mine. The layout is already ok....they just want to make it less the spacing. Is this Possible?

Comment: It is not possible to use CSS with a TextView. So no, I don't think it's possible. I would use multiple TextView's in your case.